# flutter keyboard done button to search

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, flutter-dependencies

Now a time keyboard unfocuses (Disappear) by hitting the done button. I want to search by using that done button on the flutter and unfocus keyboard. Is there any possible way?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can use `onSubmitted` on `TextField` or `TextFormField`.

```
TextField(
   ...
   onSubmitted: (value) {
      // Call search method
   }
   ....
)
```